# How to generate 2D random dataset for PCA

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I'm getting started on my ML journey. I'm using the data science handbook to learn about PCA. The following code snippet is used to generate a random 2D data set with a linear relationship. Could someone explain the intuition of how multiplying a 2x2 and 2x200 random matrices results in a linear relationship as shown in the plot?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See the usage notes for [tag:machine-learning]. Short answer: that's a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), which is not *quite* the same as multiplication. Instead it defines a set of multiplications and additions, which in this case rescales data around the origin. If there were a column of 1s and another term on the left, you can rearrange terms to get the form of a linear function: y = (m * x1) + (b * 1)

Comment: Short answer number 2 in addition to @Alexander : numpy handles the dot product of matrices as a matrix multiplication. Think of it like that: You have 200 (random) dots in an x1-x2-plane - this is the second matrix. The first matrix is the 2x2 coefficient matrix A for the (linear) transformation: Each of your 200 dots (of dimension 2x1) gets multiplied with it, resulting in new coordinates: A*(x1,x2)=(a11*x1+a12*x2, a21*x1+a22*x2). It's a two-dimensional mapping that "scales" each dimension linearly and if the off-diagonal is not 0, the dimensions influence each other, hence the dependency.